# Mark targets defined by implicit rules as .SECONDARY

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For my project, it is necessary to autogenerate .c source files using m4. For my build process, I am using GNU make, for both m4 invocation and compilation of object files that are compiled from these generated .c files.

```
%.c: %.c.in
        m4 -D OPNAME=$(OPNAME) -D ARGLEVEL=$(ARGLEVEL) -D SKELARGS="$(call TOM4LIST,$(SKELARGS))" -D SUBDIRS="$(call TOM4LIST,$(RSSUBDIRS))" $(BASEDIR)/op/common.m4 $< > $@
```

This works fine, but when compiling the corresponding .o object the .c file is automatically marked as INTERMEDIATE and gets deleted when the job is done.

I don't want this.

The documented way of preventing intermediate files from being deleted is adding the target that should be kept to the dependency list of the .SECONDARY target:

```
.SECONDARY: somefile.c
```

However, for obvious reasons,

```
.SECONDARY: %.c
```

will not work. So, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all the build steps explicit. Use the fact that a single recipe can be used to build multiple targets and specify your *metatargets* using the list of desired files, rather than %.

```
OBJECTS = a.o b.o c.o
INTERMEDIARY = $(OBJECTS:.o=.c)

OBJECTS: $(@:.o=.c)
    // build command for .c to .o

INTERMEDIARY: $(@:.c=.c.in)
     m4 -D OPNAME=$(OPNAME) -D ARGLEVEL=$(ARGLEVEL) -D SKELARGS="$(call TOM4LIST,$(SKELARGS))" -D SUBDIRS="$(call TOM4LIST,$(RSSUBDIRS))" $(BASEDIR)/op/common.m4 $< > $@
```

Comment: This requires knowledge of objects to be built beforehand which is not the case in my project. I could go with your solution, but that would require automatically processing the Makefile itself with a tool like m4 so as to fill up the OBJECTS variable with the appropriate object names.

Comment: Then do something like `SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c.inc)`, `INTERMEDIATE = $(SOURCES:.c.inc=.c)` and `.SECONDARY: $(INTERMEDIATE)`

Comment: Good idea. Thank you.